How to detect language of document content
I am currently utilizing the DeepL .NET API to develop a custom text and document translation solution. Similar to the text translation feature, where DeepL returns the detected source language, I am seeking a method to obtain the detected source language for documents to be translated.
On the DeepL website, the source language is automatically set upon uploading a document for translation. I would like to implement this same functionality in our translator. Could you please advise on how to achieve this?


How is this related to ReactJS? (If it's not, please remove the tag)

It is currently not possible to infer the detected source language for documents with the public API DeepL provides, as it just allows you to download the document. See also the documentation.
